# how can i use a variable of a function in another function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

How can I use the local variable `randomNum` declared in the first function in second function?

```js
btn.click(function() {
  var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3-0)) + 0;
})

rock.click(function() {
  // i want to use `randomNum` variable from the above function
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-should-i-use-it-or-omit-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to declare the variable outside of the function, so it will be in scope of both functions

Though remember, `randomNum` would equal `undefined` until `btn.click()` is fired.

See this JSFiddle for an example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lo8c2mrq/

```js
var randomNum

btn.click(function(){
  randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3-0)) + 0;
})

rock.click(function(){
  console.log(randomNum) // undefined, or the number that was assigned from btn click
});
```

Comment: i actually want to use the random number generated by the first function when the btn.click() is fired in second function. Can you tell me how ?

Comment: This answer shows you how. I updated the answer with a JSFiddle, so you can see the second function is using the value set by the first function: https://jsfiddle.net/Lo8c2mrq/

Answer (score 0):

You could create a separate function `getRandomNum()`, so you would be more flexible in case you want to change the value of `randomNum` in future. Global variable are bad in most cases, as it will be hard to track which function or part of code actually changes it.

```
var getRandomNum = function () {
  // set randomNum once
  if (typeof this.randomNum === 'undefined') {
    this.randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 0)) + 0;
  }
  return this.randomNum;
};

btn.click(function () {
  var randomNum = getRandomNum();
})

rock.click(function () {
  console.log(getRandomNum());
});
```